# How to change the name of Struts-config.xml using web.xml?

Tags: java, struts-1

I want to change the name of `struts.config.xml` file to another name something like `abc.xml` using the `web.xml`. Is it possible to rename the `struts.config.xml` using the `web.xml` file or any other way to rename it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just rename the file itself, it should be in your `WEB-INF` folder together with the `web.xml` file. You also need to do a small change in the `web.xml` file (abc.xml below).

```
<init-param>
<param-name>config</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/abc.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```